# Notation for element of a set on which some function is minimal

Tags: notation

*This is a simple notation question about something I seem to have forgotten, have a complete mental block to remembering, and can't find online. I think there's an equally simple answer.*

Suppose I have (for instance) a set $S$
and some injective function $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
There's a standard notation to indicate the minimum value that $f$
takes on the elements of $S$:
$$\underset{x\in S}{\rm{min}}\{f(x)\}.$$
But what if,
instead,
I want to indicate the element of $S$
that achieves this minimal value?
I could just write
$$\{x\in S\mid f(x)\text{ is minimal}\}$$
but I feel like there is a better notation,
resembling the one above,
that I cannot remember.

Comment: Some people use [$\operatorname{argmin}$ and $\operatorname{argmax}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max).

Comment: @logarithm I thought I remembered something different, but it seems your answer is the answer.  Would you consider posting it as an answer so I can accept it?